# Exporting images from a list to drive fails without error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am mapping over a function that returns images, more specifically changemaps made with the LandTrendr API, which are *ee.Images* (according to the [LandTrendr for GEE homepage](https://emapr.github.io/LT-GEE/api.html#getchangemap)).

I end up with a list (see print output in code below) of images and want to use a for-loop to write them to my Google drive. (I am aware that for-loops are deprecated in GEE.)

However, **no task is created and no error is thrown**, leaving me puzzled to what is wrong/missing.

Here is a reproducible example. If you have not used LandTrendr before and want to run this example you have to visit [this](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/emaprlab/public) site first to add the API to your account.

```
var years = ee.List.sequence(1985, 1995, 5);
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point(13.64, 55.9552).buffer(500);

var imageList = years.map(function(n) {

// define landtrendr parameters
var startYear = 1985;
var endYear =  1995;
var startDay = '06-20';
var endDay = '09-10';
var index = 'NDVI';
var maskThese = ['cloud', 'shadow', 'snow', 'water'];

var runParams = { 
  maxSegments:            6,
  spikeThreshold:         0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: false,
  recoveryThreshold:      0.9,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};

var strt = ee.Number(n)
var nd = ee.Number(n).add(5)

// define change parameters
var changeParams = {
  delta:  'loss',
  sort:   'greatest',
  year:   {checked:true, start: strt, end: nd},
  mag:    {checked:false, value:100,  operator:'>'},
  dur:    {checked:false, value:5,    operator:'<'},
  preval: {checked:false, value:300,  operator:'>'},
  mmu:    {checked:false, value:11},
};

// load the LandTrendr.js module
var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js'); 

// add index to changeParams object
changeParams.index = index;

// run landtrendr
var ftvList = ['NDVI'];
var lt = ltgee.runLT(startYear, endYear, startDay, endDay, aoi, index, ftvList, runParams, maskThese);

// get the change map layers
var changeImg = ltgee.getChangeMap(lt, changeParams);

return changeImg
  
});

print(imageList) //Output below

//List (3 elements)
  //0: Image (6 bands)
    //type: Image
    //bands: List (6 elements)
      //0: "yod", signed int16, EPSG:4326
      //1: "mag", double, EPSG:4326
      //2: "dur", double, EPSG:4326
      //3: "preval", double, EPSG:4326
      //4: "rate", double, EPSG:4326
      //5: "dsnr", double, EPSG:4326
  //1: Image (6 bands)
  //2: Image (6 bands)


for (var i = 0; i<imageList.length; i++) {
  
  // get changemap from list
  var im = imageList.get(i)
  // Export band named 'mag' as GeoTiff
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image: im.select(['mag']),
  description: 'changemap_'+i,
  scale: 30,
  region: aoi,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  maxPixels: 3991919404
  
});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 bugs in your code.

1. `ee.List.length` is a function. To execute that function you need to call it using `ee.List.length()`
2. `ee.List.get(i)` returns the i'th element in an object form. If you want to call any function on the resulting object (like `.select()`) you need to force cast it to `ee.Image()` type like this `var im = ee.Image(imageList.get(i))`

After these 2 fixes, the code works fine. [Link to corrected code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a20ce434f7a3d7dc8e92bffd4a7d50c9)

Note: Depending on your computer's RAM, this code may hang. For batch exports, GEE recommends using their python API and the function `ee.batch.Export()` function.